Janka hardness of Carbon Fiber
I know that Janka hardness is a measurement used for wood. However since I want to build a guitar made of several materials I got curious whether anyone has ever used the Janka test to determine the resistance of carbon fiber. I couldn't find any sources online. Is anyone aware of such test or can at least speculate based on other tests how carbon fiber would perform in a Janka hardness test? Any ideas?

carbon fiber itself is like thread and is quite flexible ... are you talking about something else?
